# Using "sub()" in jq v1.6 errors in "sub is not defined"

Tags: syntax, jq

i keep running into the error "sub is not defined" when using jq version 1.6

for example: `"bar" | sub("b","f")`
(see on jqplay: https://jqplay.org/s/ggmuK5WvZF)

here is a link to the documentation: https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/v1.6/#sub(regex;tostring)sub(regex;string;flags)

what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Its a minor typo, the `sub()` function along with the other functions in `jq` takes arguments separated by `;` and not `,` which is an operator in the context of `jq`. It should have been written as

```
sub("b"; "f")
```

The error is likely because the runtime wasn't able to match the your call to to the actual signature of the `sub()` function.